# angular POST request ends up being GET in Chrome Network Tab

Tags: angular

Ugh...I am making a POST request using ng http service but browser makes GET instead. I tried to use XMLHttpRequest and it does it correctly. Any clue why this may happen?

```
let body = { test: 'here'};
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post('https://httpbin.org/post', JSON.stringify(body), options)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about posting the offending code?

Comment: Added the code. Updated the post endpoint, it is public https://httpbin.org/post so it should work.

Comment: It's working for me [in this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/io32JKSpLIAp0vggUW89?p=preview) is there anything you have done differently? I just copied your method exactly